# Why this code don't pollute the prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security

I was watching some videos about prototype pollution in JavaScript, it seems that my code should be affected but testing code don't work:

```js
// jQuery mock
var $ = {
    isArray: (x) => x instanceof Array
};


var Clone = {
    clone_object: function(object) {
        var tmp = {};
        if (typeof object === 'object') {
            if ($.isArray(object)) {
                return this.clone_array(object);
            } else if (object === null) {
                return object;
            } else {
                for (var key in object) {
                    if ($.isArray(object[key])) {
                        tmp[key] = this.clone_array(object[key]);
                    } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
                        tmp[key] = this.clone_object(object[key]);
                    } else {
                        tmp[key] = object[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    },
    clone_array: function(array) {
        if (!is_function(Array.prototype.map)) {
            throw new Error("Your browser don't support ES5 array map " +
                            'use es5-shim');
        }
        return array.slice(0).map(function(item) {
            if (typeof item === 'object') {
                return this.clone_object(item);
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
};

var clone = function(object) {
    return Clone.clone_object(object);
};

var x = JSON.parse('{"__proto__": {"foo": 10}}');
console.log(x);
var y = clone(x);
console.log(y);
var z = {};
console.log(z.foo);
```

Is prototype pollution something that don't work anymore or there is issue with my code? If issue is with the code what would need to be changed to pollution happen when calling clone function?

Comment: I don't know the exact definition of "prototype pollution", but if your code clones objects, that have prototypes, which in turn have enumerable properties, then `for ... in` without any additional `hasOwnProperty` is probably not the best idea.

Comment: What is it about your code that you think might affect any prototype properties?

Comment: Nothing in that code modifies prototypes. Am I missing something?

Comment: In particular, setting the `__proto__` property on an object does not affect its actual prototype chain.

Comment: @Pointy it really doesn't? I thought it was some deprecated legacy happy hippo, that allowed you access to the internal [[Prototype]]: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @ASDFGerte well I guess it still works; I thought that had gone away as of a while ago but perhaps not.

Comment: I was watching this video and it shows that simple merge is vulnerable to prototype pollution I do the same thing here [Olivier Arteau -- Prototype pollution attacks in NodeJS applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUsiFV3dsK8)

Comment: @Pointy the video I've linked (didn't tested its code) showed merge with for..in and update the prop of one object with value of the other, recursively. I do the same here.

Comment: @Pointy if you modify `({}).__proto__.x = 10` you change every Object `console.log(({}).x);`, added answer to my question I do different thing here because I change not update previous `__proto__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is:

This is vulnerable:

```
({}).__proto__.x = 10
console.log(({}).x);
```

but this is not

```
var tmp = {}
var tmp2 = {x: 10};
tmp.__proto__ = tmp2;
```

because the first example *mutates* the existing `__proto__` object, but the second example replaces the whole `__proto__` property, but doesn't mutate the previous `__proto__` object.

The code in the question creates a new prototype object. It does not modify the prototype of a created object.